# My iPhone turned black while testing my app it works, but the screen has been black for 20 minutes

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8.3

I tested 2 of my apps on my iPhone today. The first one went fine and worked and nothing happened. The second one was working at first however it crashed my whole phone and there is a black screen. I pressed Siri button it works and all, but no pixels or brightness just black screen. Is there anyway to fix this problem or do I have to go to the Apple Store or get a new iPhone. It was my first time testing. Someone please help me.

Comment: you should list a few things you tried already. 1.) I'd personally try holding down the power to reset it. 2.) unplug it from your mac, plug it back in and try using the simulator again.

Comment: btw, this would probably be a better place for this question: http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I would guess that this is the grandmother of all dupes, since "try rebooting" has been the programmer's mantra since shortly after Lady Lovelace did her thing.

Comment: ooh nice Ada reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a programming question. But try holding down the home and power button at the same time for 15 seconds. That usually works.

Answer (score 1):

Try holding the power and home buttons for ten seconds. Your iPhone will then reboot, hopefully fixing the problem.